# VS Debugger shows current value in foreach loop as null, when it is not

Tags: c#, entity-framework, debugging, entity-framework-core

In some situations when I try to debug a foreach loop, I cannot see the current value in the debugger. It will throw a null reference exception if I try to evaluate it in watch, while the code will execute with no problems. I'm not 100% certain, but this seems to happen when I'm iterating over a list that I have retrieved using EF Core.

```
var bar = await context.Bars.Include(b => b.Barlets).ToListAsync();
foreach (var foo in bar)
{
  var boop = foo;
  /*do stuff with foo */
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in the middle of the loop, foo will be null. At the same breakpoint I can view the contents of bar with no problems and none of the values are null. I can also view the contents of boop just fine, but not foo, even right after the assignment.

Comment: Where do you set the breakpoints and where do you check the values,? Are you getting NullReferenceException?

Comment: In the commented part. And I check by mouseovering the variables in code, as well as in the watch window. I only get the NullReferenceException if I write foo in the watch window while debugging. The actual execution of the code is fine with no exceptions.

Comment: Use `ToList` instread of `ToListAsync`

Comment: same here with a for loop.